# formStack embedded form disappears after a second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, embed

I'm trying to figure out why a formstack form that I've embedded on a site always appears for a split second then disappears.

Site is here: [enter link description here](http://myotechnology.com)

I thought it was the slide show at first but it happens on every page. Also the page jumps downwards at the same time that the form disappears. Idk if they are connected. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you strip out the referral link on non-paid plans.